# I keep failing the ProctorU "Testing Your Equipment" test and I don't know why

Tags: firefox, cpu

I am trying to test my equipment on Firefox to make sure I can take the LSAT through ProctorU, but ProctorU gives me this message when I test:

```
CPU model name: Your CPU Model Name could not be found.
CPU core count: Your CPU Core Count could not be found.
CPU architecture: Your CPU Architecture could not be found.
CPU usage: [NOT FOUND] Maximum CPU usage is 95%. Your current CPU usage could not be found.
RAM size: [NOT FOUND] Minimum RAM size is 1 GB. Your RAM size could not be found.
RAM usage: [NOT FOUND] Maximum RAM usage is 100%. Your current RAM usage could not be found.
```

ProctorU's error message says this could be because the ProctorU extension isn't downloaded (it is) or because of privacy settings on my browser (which I have turned off on the proctorU page). I am out of ideas, any thoughts?

EDIT: Thanks everybody for the suggestions, I have tried them but unfortunately the problem persists. I will update my post if I figure out the issue.

Comment: Seems like the software needs Admin to probe your hardware, but thats just a guess. Also you may want to create a new user just to run the software, so you can disable app startup and stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Firefox are the only supported browsers for the ProctorU extension. Try installing the ProctorU extension on Chrome.

Ensure that your browser is up to date and you have the [ProctorU extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proctoru/goobgennebinldhonaajgafidboenlkl) installed.

**How to Update Chrome**

1. In the top right, click *More* **⋮**
2. Click *Help*.
3. Click *About Google Chrome*.
4. If out of date, Chrome will automatically begin updating and will require that the browser is restarted to take effect.

If your browser is Firefox ensure that Firefox is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and other secure browsers hide computer information, such as CPU model, to prevent tracking by computer characteristics called [fingerprinting](https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/how-to-block-fingerprinting-with-firefox/), which explains why the information below was missing:

```
CPU model name: Your CPU Model Name could not be found.
CPU core count: Your CPU Core Count could not be found.
CPU architecture: Your CPU Architecture could not be found.
```

Chrome probably has similar security features.

If you want to use Firefox, [turn off fingerprinting security](https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/how-to-block-fingerprinting-with-firefox/).

You can [adjust these security settings in Firefox](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-block-fingerprinting-in-firefox/).

[image: Firefox Security Settings]

- Enter *about:preferences* in the URL bar, or navigate the from the menu.
- Select *Privacy & Security*.
- Choose a *Custom* setting.
- Remove the check mark from *Fingerprinters*.
- You might also need to remove checks on *Cookies* and *Tracking content*.

Log into *ProctorU* and again attempt to use your Firefox browser to take tests.

**N.B.** This setting intentionally reduces privacy. When not on *ProctorU*, revert to more secure settings.